# Debug a deployed application via PC | iOS or Android

Tags: android, ios, windows, debugging, remote-debugging

I am doing research into debugging/sniffing applications that are installed into my mobile device (Android or iOS). For example, is it possible to debug the data/processes of a deployed app, this can be any app download via the app store for example.

I am not referring to using an inspector to see the "html" content. I have heard people plugging their phone in to PC via USB to do such things but don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

## Android

> android:debuggable Whether or not the application can be debugged,
> even when running on a device in user mode — "true" if it can be, and
> "false" if not. The default value is "false".

Applications on Play have this set to false.